# Loop for checkbox controls for mulitple checkboxes

Tags: c++, visual-studio, checkbox, mfc

Is there an easier way to do this?

```
void CheckboxsDlg::DoDataExchange(CDataExchange* pDX){
    CDialogEx::DoDataExchange(pDX);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK1, m_Checkbox1);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK2, m_Checkbox2);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK3, m_Checkbox3);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK4, m_Checkbox4);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK5, m_Checkbox5);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK6, m_Checkbox6);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK7, m_Checkbox7);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK8, m_Checkbox8);
    DDX_Control(pDX, IDC_CHECK9, m_Checkbox9);
}
```

... (with more checkboxes to be added).
Can this process be looped in some fashion to create 100 more?
I'm using visual studios 2015 as my ide.
Thanks.

Comment: Store your checkbox variables in a list, instead of naming them individually. Also getting a form containing more than let's say 10 checkboxes at once is incredibly bad UI design, and will achieve a bad user experience. Don't do such please.

Comment: 100 checkboxes - think of the poor end-user..  If you are doing some sort of board game you can program the board UI with one owner-draw button and test where in the button the mouse was clicked.

Comment: Use a list view control with `LVS_EX_CHECKBOXES` style instead.

Comment: I'm just saying 100 as an extreme example of repetition.  I have no intention of using that many.  I was just looking for another way to do this instead of way it is being shown (1 thru 9 etc...)